# SQL table update frequency in Seconds with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, sql-update

I have a form where different users can update data. I have implemented a write protection script with AJAX to avoid conflicts if more then one user is working in the form. As i do not know it better ;) i have solved this in that way:

If the user open form the related user_id and timestamp will be updated in my SQL table for the specific form ID. With AJAX i check every 3 seconds if this user is still on the form and do a update of the timestamp. If another user is opening the form in parallel, i check if this timestamp is older then 10 seconds. If this is true i update the SQL table with the new user_id and timestamp every 3 seconds. If the timestamp from the first user is not older then 10 seconds i just lock the form by adding a overlay with a high z-index. So the user can see the infomation but can not change it. I also show a information that this form is currently locked.

This sounds simple and is working ... more or less...

**Here comes my problem:**

It seems like that due to for me some unknown reason the SQL table does not gets updated every 3 seconds. (Edit:) I is working correctly sometimes for a longer time. But sometimes but not very often the SQL update is not initiated within 9 seconds (this is 3 tries). I added my script bellow, may be my routine is not optimal for my needs? Would be happy if you can help me to optimize it to avoid those update delays (hicks).

I am working local. Using the XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.4. PHP Version 7.4.6

**Code in my frontend page:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 var auto_refresh = setInterval(
     function() {
         $('#login')
             .load('ajax-audit_execute_login.php?audit_id=<?= $audit_id ?>&user_id=<?= $user['id'] ?>');
     }, 3000); // refresh every 3000 milliseconds
</script>

<div id="login">
<?php
    // Check if someone is logged in into that form
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT login_at, login_by FROM audit WHERE id = :id");
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':id' => $audit_id));
    $login = $statement->fetch();

    // Calculate the tim ebetween the now and the latest login timestamp
    $ts2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $ts1 = strtotime($login['login_at']);
    $seconds_diff = $ts2 - $ts1;

   // If its the same user who locked the form latest do just an update of the timestamp
    if ($login['login_by'] == $user['id']) {        
        $query = "UPDATE audit  
        SET login_at = :login_at, 
        login_by = :login_by  
        WHERE id = :audit_id";
        $pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":login_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), ':audit_id' => $audit_id, ':login_by' => $user['id']));  
        
        $locked = 0; // Form is not locked
        
    } else {
       // If its another user check if the timestamp is older then 10 seconds
        if ($seconds_diff > 10) {
            // The timestamp is older then 10 seconds. Update the SQL data for new user.
            $query = "UPDATE audit  
            SET login_at = :login_at, 
            login_by = :login_by  
            WHERE id = :audit_id";
            $pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":login_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), ':audit_id' => $audit_id, ':login_by' => $user['id']));
            
            $locked = 0; // Form is unlocked for the new user
            
        } else {
            // Timestamp is not older so the form is locked
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT users.vorname, users.nachname, companies.company_name 
                                        FROM users 
                                        JOIN companies ON users.cid = companies.cid 
                                        WHERE users.id = :id");
            $result = $statement->execute(array(':id' => $login['login_by']));
            $locked_by = $statement->fetch();

            $locked = 1; // Form is locked
        }
    }
    ?>

<?php if ($locked == 1) { ?>
  <style>
    div.fadeMe {
        opacity: 0.1;
        background: #000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
<?php 
// If the form is locked adding a transparent overlay to avoid changes on the form.
// Add a alert and inform the user about the situation.
?>
<div class="fadeMe"></div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-0 mb-0 rounded-0" role="alert">
         <p class="mb-0 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-lock mr-1"></i> 
            Die Bearbeitung dieses Fragebogens ist durch <?=$locked_by['vorname']?> <?=$locked_by['nachname']?> [<?=$locked_by['company_name']?>] gesperrt. </p>
   </div>
 <?php } else { ?>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**My code in the AJAX file in "background":**
Which is more or less the same as in the front end.

```html
<?php
$audit_id = $_GET['audit_id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
?>

<div id="login">
<?php
    // Check if someone is logged in into that form
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT login_at, login_by FROM audit WHERE id = :id");
    $result = $statement->execute(array(':id' => $audit_id));
    $login = $statement->fetch();

    // Calculate the tim ebetween the now and the latest login timestamp
    $ts2 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $ts1 = strtotime($login['login_at']);
    $seconds_diff = $ts2 - $ts1;

   // If its the same user who locked the form latest do just an update of the timestamp
    if ($login['login_by'] == $user_id) {        
        $query = "UPDATE audit  
        SET login_at = :login_at, 
        login_by = :login_by  
        WHERE id = :audit_id";
        $pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":login_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), ':audit_id' => $audit_id, ':login_by' => $user_id));  
        
        $locked = 0; // Form is not locked
        
    } else {
       // If its another user check if the timestamp is older then 10 seconds
        if ($seconds_diff > 10) {
            // The timestamp is older then 10 seconds. Update the SQL data for new user.
            $query = "UPDATE audit  
            SET login_at = :login_at, 
            login_by = :login_by  
            WHERE id = :audit_id";
            $pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($query);
            $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":login_at" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), ':audit_id' => $audit_id, ':login_by' => $user_id));
            
            $locked = 0; // Form is unlocked for the new user
            
        } else {
            // Timestamp is not older so the form is locked
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT users.vorname, users.nachname, companies.company_name 
                                        FROM users 
                                        JOIN companies ON users.cid = companies.cid 
                                        WHERE users.id = :id");
            $result = $statement->execute(array(':id' => $login['login_by']));
            $locked_by = $statement->fetch();

            $locked = 1; // Form is locked
        }
    }
    ?>

<?php if ($locked == 1) { ?>
  <style>
    div.fadeMe {
        opacity: 0.1;
        background: #000;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
<?php 
// If the form is locked adding a transparent overlay to avoid changes on the form.
// Add a alert and inform the user about the situation.
?>
<div class="fadeMe"></div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-0 mb-0 rounded-0" role="alert">
         <p class="mb-0 text-center">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-lock mr-1"></i> 
            <?php 
            // just for development purpose only to see the reaction time on the SQL update
            // See every 3 seconds the updated time stamp and the calculated time difference in sseconds.
            echo $login['login_at'];
            echo " ";
            echo $seconds_diff 
            ?> 
            Die Bearbeitung dieses Fragebogens ist durch <?=$locked_by['vorname']?> <?=$locked_by['nachname']?> [<?=$locked_by['company_name']?>] gesperrt. </p>
   </div>
 <?php } else { ?>
 <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there's a looooooot of issues here.

1. If you're gunna do any sort of ongoing validation, you don't return the entire HTML body every request, you return a small JSON reply and use that to control the HTML via JS.  Generally it's a good practice to separate your HTML \ JS from your API \ validation layer altogether.
2. You shouldn't be managing data locks on the front end at all.  Trusting the client to maintain data integrity is a big no-no in general. It seems like this should be handled as some sort of batched queue.  You should never "recreate that effect" via locking and unlocking forms client side.
3. Your "silent" form key (or any validation stuff) should be handled via sessions or OAUTH, not GET params.

That said the issue is most likely a result of a race condition cause by table locking.  If 2 users are both trying to lock \ access records which have a gap overlap user 2 has to wait until user 1's lock releases on that range.

This in turn makes the PHP "silently" block requests while they wait on the table locks to release.  If you didn't properly index your user \ timestamp columns with the above queries, it could put a lock on all the other users update queries while it waits depending on how you set up your indexes...  Which can then lead to your timer creating callback hell since every user is running it the whole time their logged in.

You should log your DB response time specifically to pin down if this is an issue, but regardless there's some architectural issues that should be addressed regardless.

Comment: Hi Mason, lets stick on my problem. Of course i do not ignore your recommendations but i would like to understand the conflict here. I have difficulties to understand exactly what you see as reason (process) that sometimes the update does not work. As i understood you identified the problem that two users try to unlock, but based on my code this is not possible due to the first check of the time difference. Before that, everything is SELECT only. The UPDATE comes only if the time difference is given. And if this is true, the other user shall not longer be on the same form.

Comment: To your point 2: Not sure how a client can change here something because the script is running in any way if the user opens that page. For my understanding its already batched as i run the check automatically every 3rd second.